# Finding Optimization of Rectangle

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have the following problem and I want to find the minimum.

A rectangle fence is being built. One side of the rectangle costs 5 dollars per foot, while the other 3 sides cost 3 dollars per foot. The total square footage is 300.

How do I find the minimum?

Comment: Take a variable, make an expression, find its derivative, set it to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Lets call the sides of the rectangle $a$ and $b$. If $a(x)=x$ then we know that the area of the rectangle has to be $300$, so $ab=300\Rightarrow xb = 300 \Rightarrow b(x) = \frac{300}{x}$. Now consider a function $p(x)$ price. This function will be $p(x)=5a(x)+3b(x)=5x+3\frac{300}{x}$, defined of course just for positive $x$. Now find the derivative and the critical points. Chose the critical point with physic meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Set up two equations. One using the footage, the other using the price of the fence per foot.
Then substitute an expression for one variable into the equation (function) with the prize.
Last, find the derivative of this function and set it equal to zero.